# Laravel Nova. Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '*.deleted_at'

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-10, laravel-nova, soft-delete

I'm using Laravel Nova 4 (Laravel 10.43.0, PHP 8.2.8).
When using soft deletion, I get the error `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '*.deleted_at'`, where `*` is the table of the entity for which I use it.
Full SQL request in the exception:

```sql
select * from `users` where `id` = 1 and `users`.`deleted_at` is null limit 1
```

If I execute this query in the SQL console in PhpStorm, it will say that there is no such column, but the query itself will execute and do it correctly. An example of an implementation with a user.
[image]
[image]

Migration:

```php
// ...
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    // ...
    $table->softDeletes();
    // ...
});
```

Model:

```php
// ...
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    // ...
    use SoftDeletes;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: i can'z see that you use softdelete anywhere

Comment: @nbk nova uses this "under the hood". I don't use it explicitly. Check this - https://youtu.be/M61j5W6P5Bc?list=PLFHz2csJcgk8hFHA0x8yiuSWC0PR17UzW&t=484

Comment: your user table has not the column deteleted _at, if softDeletes doesn't add the column, it will never be there

Comment: @nbk I have attached a screenshot that shows that this column is there...

Comment: @nbk [$table->softDeletes();](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/migrations#column-method-softDeletes) will create a `deleted_at` column when migrating

Comment: @nbk yes, `$table->softDeletes();` is already in my migration, I provided the entire migration file in the question. You can see it there

Comment: Can you show your actual table schema?

Comment: @aynber yes, I uploaded the second screenshot with the schema of this table

Answer (score 0):

The source of the problem has been found. There were three files in the root of my project: `.env`, `.env.local`, `.env.prod`, the last two were used by the console command to quickly change the environment. After I put the `.env.*` files in a separate folder, the application began to work like clockwork.